# MyBatis with postgres throws "ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I am using MyBatis to do a very simple select in a postgres database in a java web based application

Setup is as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the the following driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1004-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

The mapper looks as follows:

```
<select id="getLicenseUsage"  parameterType="long"  resultMap="licenseUsage">
    select ('1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT'::timestamp + (event_time/1000)::text::interval)::date as day, license_key, count(distinct event_id) as recos, max(id) as venm_id
    from venm_raw
    where target_id is not null and id > #{fromId}
    group by license_key,day;
</select>
```

When i execute this query i get the following error:

```
"ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist"
```

From the different readings over the net, it seems that MyBatis is looking behind the scenes for a table named "dual" which exists in Oracle but not in postgres. This is just a guess at this point.

I am stuck here, help s much appreciated. Thx in advance.

Full trace below:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist)
### The error may exist in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/mappers/redshift/LicenseUsageMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.qualcomm.vuforia.redshift.mappers.LicenseUsageMapper.getLicenseUsage
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist)
        at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:75)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.selectList(Unknown Source)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:198)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:114)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:58)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getLicenseUsage(Unknown Source)
        at com.qualcomm.vuforia.sumtables.summarizers.SummarizerProcessor.process(SummarizerProcessor.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
```

Comment: What do your *Mybatis* config XML and properties look like? It looks like the setup XML you posted is the *Maven* dependencies, but not the *Mybatis* config.

Comment: I didn't configure any MyBatis config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace of the error I can say that apache database connection pool is used. And it looks like it has `validationQuery` configured to something like `SELECT 1 FROM dual`. mybatis itself does not use dbcp and has its own implementation for pooled datasource so this dbcp is something that is configured in your project.

As you were able to figure out `dual` does not exist in postgres so you need to change that query to `SELECT 1`. There are many ways to use dbcp so you need to find how it is used and configured in your project.

You are using spring so most probably you have [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) configured in spring context with `validationQuery` set.

The other way is to do a full text search for `dual` in your project.

Comment: You are right. The root cause was the validation query used which had dual in it. Thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response that you don't have any config setup, I suspect that that may be the crux of the issue here.

Check out the [Getting Started Guide](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) for an overview, and the [config section](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html) for more details.

The example config they listed in the *Getting Started* tutorial is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
  <environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
      <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
      <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="${driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
      </dataSource>
    </environment>
  </environments>
  <mappers>
    <mapper resource="org/mybatis/example/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Which in turn hooks into a *properties* file to set the environment variables such as `${driver}` et al.

In particular, you would likely want to focus on these settings:

```
<property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"/>
```

Where `localhost` changes to your host name, and `db` is the name of your database. `5432` is generally the default port with *Postgres*, but if your port is non-standard, you'll want to change that as well.